# MIPS assembly - Reading from a file with hexadecimal values

Tags: assembly, hex, mips

here is my question.

I want to read from a txt/dat file using MIPS assembly. Problem is that everyting in the file is hexadecimal such as 0x54ebcda7. When i try to read and load this into a register, MARS simulator reads it with the ascii values. I don't want this and need the "actual value" of that hexadecimal number? how do i do that?

Comment: You're question is a bit unclear. Is your file a binary file with byte sequences like `A7 CD EB 54`, or is it a text file with strings like `0x54ebcda7`?

Comment: It is a file with strings like 0x54ebcda7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to show how this could be done in C, which should be easy enough for you to translate into MIPS assembly:

```
// Assume that data from the file has been read into a char *buffer
// Assume that there's an int32_t *values where the values will be stored

while (bufferBytes) {
    c = *buffer++;
    bufferBytes--;

    // Consume the "0x" prefix, then read digits until whitespace is found
    if (c == '0' && prefixBytes == 0) {
        prefixBytes++;
    } else if (c == 'x' && prefixBytes == 1) {
        prefixBytes++;
    } else {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            if (prefixBytes == 2) {
                // Reached the end of a number. Store it and start over
                prefixBytes = 0;
                *values++ = currValue;
                currValue = 0;
            } else if (prefixBytes == 0) {
                // IGNORE (whitespace in between numbers)
            } else {
                // ERROR
            }
        } else if (prefixBytes == 2) {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                c -= '0';
            } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
                c -= ('a'-10);
            } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
                c -= ('A'-10);
            } else {
                // ERROR
            }
            currValue = (currValue << 4) | c;
        } else {
            // ERROR
        }
    }
}
// Store any pending value that was left when reaching the end of the buffer
if (prefixBytes == 2) {
    *values++ = currValue;
}
```

Comment: It is not easily translatable, a character in hexadecimal is 4 bits. An ascii character is 8 bits. Since you do not deal with registers in C language a conversion code may function well in C. However if you try to apply this code to MIPS assembly then you have to deal with registers. A register is 32 bit and can hold a hexadecimal value of 8 characters. When you read them as ascii characters you basically put 8 hexadecimal characters into 2 registers and since the minimum data you can reach is a byte this makes the conversion totally different from C language.

Comment: When I asked you earlier in a comment you said that the numbers were stored in the file as strings. Each character in the string will be one byte (assuming ASCII encoding), e.g. `'0'`, `'x'`, '`5`' and so on (which you can read with the `LBU` instruction). I maintain that it'd be fairly easy to translate this into MIPS assembly, you just have to spend some time on it.

Comment: @BerkayDincer: Any legal C-code is easily translatable into MIPS by any MIPS C-compiler, or indeed by any competent MIPS assembly programmer. This includes Michael's conversion code.