# Read MIPS String if String Contains an Integer

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to create an assembly-language program (in MIPS) that reads user-input values that are separated with newlines. I want to read a string that has an integer in it (for example, "A4" ,but instead, MIPS reads the string as "A" and the integer as "4". How do I make MIPS read the string as "A4" with syscall? Here's the bit of my code that I have so far, which is supposed to read a String on one line, and an integer on the next line.

```
buffer: .space 2
.text
.globl main
main:
li $v0, 8
la $a0, buffer
li $a1, 2
syscall
move $s0, $a0


li $v0, 5               
syscall
move $s1, $v0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System call 8 reads at most `$a1-1` characters, because it always NUL-terminates the string. So by setting `$a1` to 2 and then inputting `"A4"` you will get the string `"A\0"` in `buffer`. If you want to be able to read 2 characters plus the NUL-terminator, set `$a1` to 3 instead.

Comment: thanks. that's what i had thought at first, but initially i wasn't sure

Comment: This change also requires `buffer: .space 3`

Comment: now it's saying that the integer input for syscall 5 is invalid when i hit enter to input the integer.

Comment: @SufiIman "A5" is not valid decimal integer. It may be valid hexadecimal integer, but if you are under MARS/SPIM (looks so from the syscall used), it doesn't have hexa-string-to-value syscall, so you have to convert it on your own probably. I would bet there's some Q+A on SO with "mips hexadecimal input", like for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/16693274/4271923 (but this one looks more like good hint, you can search for more of them...)

Comment: _"now it's saying that the integer input for syscall 5 is invalid when i hit enter to input the integer."_ System call 8 will not wait for you to press the carriage return key if you've already reached the maximum number of characters that it is allowed to write to the buffer. So if you set `$a1` to 3 and then input "A4", the system call will write "A4\0" to the buffer and then return. So the carriage return key press is read by system call 5, which probably is why you're getting that message about invalid input.